# Define: Small Boy With A Pattern Syndrome

Tags: design-patterns

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059077/good-oo-design-the-singleton-design-pattern/4059161#4059161) references "Small Boy With A Pattern Syndrome." Although I can infer some meaning by context, I don't fully understand.

What is a good definition for "Small Boy With A Pattern Syndrome"?

Comment: "to the man with a hammer, every problem looks like a nail"

Comment: +1. Never heard this name before but I like it & I think I'll use it to taunt a colleague :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It simply means someone who looks for ways to inject patterns into everything, whether or not they are apropos. Think of someone who wants to turn everything into a singleton, or use factories to build everything.